# Finding addresses of called functions C

Tags: linux, pointers, x86, stack

I want to find addresses of functions on stack without using builtin macros or some library functions.(I know that all functions are called with call rel32) So what I want to do is: get address of local variable, iterate through stack looking for 0xe8 byte (opcode of call) and if I find it function's address should be 5 bytes further. This is what I have know:

```
extern void *__libc_stack_end;
void stack_show() {
   int x;
   for (uint8_t* i = &x; i < __libc_stack_end; i++) {   
       if(i == 0xe8) {
           int64_t *a = i + 5;
           printf("%p\n", a);
       }
   }  
}
```

But it doesn't work. I'm not sure if types of my variables are OK.I'm using Linux and x86 architecture.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Opcodes are not on the stack. Opcodes are code, the stack contains data.

Comment: @n.m. So it should be : if (*i == 0ex8) ?

Comment: You're talking specifically about Linux and x86 right ? Please tag appropriately and make this clear in your question.

Comment: @PaulR Yes, sorry I forgot to add it.

Comment: Why should a stack contain a pointer to a call instruction? This generally doesn't happen. Besides, if you dereference random junk, you will get a segfault.

Comment: The function's code and the stack space associated with a call to it are not kept together.  Think about what would happen with recursion, where there's still only one copy of the function's *code*, but more than one set of arguments and local variables.

Comment: You can only do this if you can access the `bp` register and know the calling convention.

Comment: @n.m. So what should I do is check for every address if in executable code 5 bytes before it is call instruction and if it's true this is some function's address?

Comment: You need to find out the return address of the function and then find an instruction before that address.

Comment: Also don't forget about function pointers... if you just need the address of a specific function, all this is unnecessary (the bare function name without the parentheses will give you that).

Comment: @n.m. Ok, but how can I do this?

Comment: @Dmitri I need addresses of all functions on stack.

Comment: There's a library function for printing a stack trace. Why don't you look at its source code to see how it works?

Comment: You need to do something in assembly. I would have no idea what exactly. Probably examine some registers.